# Conditional dependency of .NET Framework version in WIX project

Tags: .net, wix

I have a special situation that I need to check .NET framework installation based on the features that the user has selected in a WIX project.

Let's say that I have the following .WXS snippet.

```
<Feature Id="VS2008" Title="VS 2008 Support" Level="1" Display="expand">
    <ComponentRef Id="DesignTimeAssembly_2008" />
</Feature>
<Feature Id="VS2012" Title="VS 2012 Support" Level="1" Display="expand">
    <ComponentRef Id="DesignTimeAssembly_2012" />
</Feature>
```

My requirement is, if the user has selected to install the "VS 2012 Support" feature, I need to make sure that my client has installed .NET Framework 4.5.2. My VS 2012 design time component relies on .NET 4.5.2, while the VS 2008 one only relies on .NET 3.5 which is already installed by VS 2008.

I know how to setup the condition at the project level using WixNetFxExtension, but I am just not sure how to do it if the condition check needs to be done when a particular feature is selected.

Can someone please help? Thanks!